# Finding the coordinates of a point on a curve via tangents

Tags: calculus

Question: $P(x_1,y_1)$ is a point on the curve $y=e^{ - x}$. The tangent to the curve at P passes through the origin. Find the coordinates of $P$. NB: I am assuming the question is asking for an integer or some sort of value for the coordinates.

My working out: Firstly I tried the first derivative, which is $y=-e^{ - x}$ and the subbing in $x=x_1$ from point $P$ - this is this gradient for point $P$

but that just goes to get: $y=-e^{ - x_1}$, and if that's it then subbing it into the point-gradient formula ($y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$)

leading to:

$y-y_1=y=-e^{ - x_1}(x-x_1)$ etc... BUT continuing on does not get me the coordinates of $P$.

or I tried the simple method which was; $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ by using the point $P$ coordinates  and the origion (assuming it's $O(0,1)$) from the original formula. But I have no idea how I would go on from here.

Comment: Anyone? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close we have that $y_1=e^{-x_1}$. 
Then we have the tangent line at a point is
$$
y-e^{-x_1}=-e^{-x_1}(x-x_1)
$$
But now the tangent line has to go through the origin so we get,
$$
x_1e^{-x_1}=-e^{-x_1}.
$$
This means $x_1 =-1$ so we get the point $(-1,e^{1})$

Comment: Why does $y_1=e^{-x_1}$? Nevermind lol, just couldn't see it.

Comment: the origin would be at the coordinates $O(0,1)$ how does that translate to the transition from $y-e^{-x_1}=-e^{-x_1}(x-x_1)$ to $x_1e^{-x_1}=e^{-x_1}?$

Comment: Yes that edit makes more sense thank you :), also I thought for the point-gradient formula you couldn't sub in values for $y$ and $x$ but apparently you can.

Comment: I do not know what you mean with coordinate $O(0,1)$. But I believe the origin they mention in the question is just the regular origin $(0,0)$. I made a minus mistake, I edited it. Hopefully it clarifies my solution.

Comment: Well through the formula $y=e^{-x_1}$, the y-intercept is at $(0,1)$, I thought that would've been the origin. But it isn't?

Comment: No, I it is just the regular origin. Otherwise you could simply take the tangent line at the point $(0,1)$, this would automatically intersect at the point $(0,1)$.